# 400 error while using port 8080 yet the page opens

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, ajax, vue.js

Im running wampserver and am creating a login system through vue, node, PHP, ajax. Using the node.js command npm run serve I run the project on port 8080 with URL localhost:8080/register. When I try to register I get the following error:

[POST http://localhost:8080/login-system/backend/api/register.php 400 (Bad Request)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt4k9.png)

the code where I set this is is in jwtservice.js:

```
login(...args) {
        return this.axiosIns.post("http://localhost:8080/login-system/backend/api/login.php", ...args);
    }

    register(...args) {
        return this.axiosIns.post("http://localhost:8080/login-system/backend/api/register.php", ...args);
    }

    forgotPassword(...args) {
        return this.axiosIns.post("http://localhost:8080/login-system/backend/api/password-reset-token.php", ...args);
    }

    resetPassword(...args) {
        return this.axiosIns.post("http://localhost:8080/login-system/backend/api/update-forgot-password.php", ...args);
    }
```

If i put http://localhost:8080/login-system/backend/api/register.php in my URL it doesn't give me a 404 so i thought that it would be the correct URL to put in.

Not sure if this helps but here's the directory tree:

[directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnpM4.png)

EDIT: And here is the code in register.php:

```
<?php
    // required headers
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
    header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

    // files needed to connect to database
    include_once 'config/vendor/autoload.php';
    include_once 'config/database.php';
    include_once 'objects/user.php';
    

    // generate json web token
    include_once 'config/core.php';
    include_once 'config/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/BeforeValidException.php';
    include_once 'config/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/ExpiredException.php';
    include_once 'config/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/SignatureInvalidException.php';
    include_once 'config/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php';
    use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

    // get database connection
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->connect();

    // instantiate user object
    $user = new User($db);

    // get posted data
    $postedData = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $data = json_decode($postedData, true );

    // set user property values
    $user->username = $data['username'];
    $user->email = $data['email'];
    $user->fullName = $data['username'];
    $user->password = $data['password'];

    //set default errors
    $emailError = null;
    $usernameError = null;

    //create the user
    if(
        !empty($user->username) &&
        !empty($user->email) &&
        !empty($user->password) &&
        $user->create()
    ) {
        $token = array(
            "iat" => $issued_at,
            "exp" => $expiration_time,
            "iss" => $issuer,
            "data" => array(
                "id" => $user->id,
                "email" => $user->email,
            )
        );

        $accessToken = JWT::encode($token, $secret);
        $refreshToken = "";

        //set response code
        http_response_code(200);

        //display message: user was created
         echo json_encode(
            array(
                "message" => ["User was created."],
                "userData" => $user,
                "accessToken" => $accessToken, 
                "refreshToken" => $refreshToken
                )    
        );
    }

    //message if unable to create user
    else if ($user->error->errorInfo) {

        if(strpos($user->error->errorInfo[2], "email"))
            $emailError = "This email is already in use.";
        if(strpos($user->error->errorInfo[2], "username"))
            $usernameError = "This username is already in use.";

        //set response code
        http_response_code(400);
        //display message: unable to create user
        echo json_encode(array("error" => array(
                                        "email" => $emailError,
                                        "username" => $usernameError
                                    )
                                )  
                        );
    }

?>
```

Any suggestions on what to try? I've tried changing the URL to just localhost but got the same 400, and I'm not sure what the URL should be. Ask for any extra context/info, and i'll edit and add it

Comment: please show the code in register.php

Comment: @LawrenceCherone added

Comment: its hitting `http_response_code(400);` check your `...args`

Comment: also why are you replacing spaces with nothing, `preg_replace('/\s+/', '',` it will bork your data

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your php services or presumably your api on a different port to 8080. For development I tend to do this just for clarity and debugging between the server and client side applications.